# Google Sheets - SendOnEdit - One column has a specific status and another column is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm completely new to using scripts in Google Sheets to automate some activities. Forums like this are prving really useful and I could do with some help around how to solve a specific scenario I have. I've managed to create a script that generates an email when a column hits a status of "Secondment Agreement Issued" (script below). I have a second column that holds the secondment start date. What I now need to do is generate an email when a record is already at the status of "Secondment Agreement Issued" and the start date subsequently changes. Any assistance gratefully appreciated.

```
`function sendMailEdit(e){
    PMO(e);
    DawnSOC(e);
   
} 

function PMO(e){

 var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 var rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,43).getValues();

 if (sh.getName() !== 'Tracker' || e.range.columnStart != 2 || e.value != "Secondment Agreement issued") return;
  
 let ref = rData[0][0];
 let name = rData[0][30];
 let status = rData[0][1];
 let start = rData[0][11];
 let end = rData[0][12];
 let email = rData[0][20];
 let job = rData[0][31];
 let grade = rData[0][25];
 let emptype = rData[0][32];
 let lm = rData[0][35];
 let dept = rData[0][23];
 let mu = rData[0][24];
 let team = rData[0][36];
 let costcentre = rData[0][38];
 let awhrs = rData[0][40];
 let camhrs = rData[0][41];
 let agsigned = rData[0][42];
 let to = "uk.pmo@camelotgroup.co.uk"+","+"emma.hill@camelotgroup.co.uk";

 let msg = "The following person has signed their Secondment Agreement and agreed a start date with Allwyn. Please arrange for them to be added to ServiceNow for Timesheeting purposes:"+ "\n"+
 "\n"+
 "Role Reference: "+ ref + "\n" +
 "Employee Name: "+ name + "\n" +
 "Secondment status: "+ status + "\n" +
 "Secondment start date: "+ start + "\n" +
 "Secondment end date: "+ end + "\n" +
 "Email Address: "+ email + "\n" +
 "Job Title: "+ job + "\n" +
 "Grade: "+ grade + "\n" +
 "Employee Type: "+ emptype + "\n" +
 "Line Manager: "+ lm + "\n" +
 "Department: "+ dept + "\n" +
 "Management Unit: "+ mu + "\n" +
 "Team: "+ team + "\n" +
 "Cost Centre: "+ costcentre + "\n" +
 "Allwyn Hours Per Week: "+ awhrs + "\n" +
 "Camelot Contracted Hours Per Week: "+ camhrs + "\n" +
 "Secondment Agreement Signed: "+ agsigned +"\n"+
 "\n"+
 "Thanks," + "\n"+
 "The People Team"


 MailApp.sendEmail(to, "Notification - Secondment Agreement Signed - Set Up In ServiceNow", msg)

}`
```